# Implement a generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic interface and I would like to implement this interface in a generic way :

```
public interface BaseBean<T> {

    public T create(T t);
    public T read(Long id);
    public T update(T t);
    public void delete(T t);

}
```

For some reason, I can't make the implementation generic as well. Eclipse implements all interface methods in non-generic way:

```
public class BaseBeanImpl<T> implements NewBaseBean {

    @Override
    public Object create(Object t) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object read(Long id) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object update(Object t) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Object t) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object find(Long id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I change:

```
public Object create(Object t)
```

to

```
public T create(T t)
```

I get a compile error. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

```
public class BaseBeanImpl<T> implements NewBaseBean
```

to

```
public class BaseBeanImpl<T> implements NewBaseBean<T>
```

When you use the raw type `NewBaseBean`, you get `Object` instead of `T` in your interface's methods.

```
public class BaseBeanImpl<T> implements NewBaseBean<T> {

  @Override
  public T create(T t) {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public T read(Long id) {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public T update(T t) {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void delete(T t) {
  }

  @Override
  public T find(Long id) {
      return null;
  }
}
```